# Including cache partition in managed package

Tags: managed-package, platform-cache

I'm trying to include a cache partition in a managed package with "Provider Free" space allocated. In my packaging org I created a cache partition with a "Provider Free" value of "1". When I install the managed package into an org I see that the cache partition was created and has the namespace of my package. However, the 1MB of "Provider Free" storage that I allocated doesn't show up. It just says "0" and doesn't have any available for me to allocate. After installation of my managed package I want the space allocated and ready to use.

How do I do this?

Edit: Here is the package installed in an org.

https://pasteboard.co/8oumFkUv7XNe.png

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show up?  What are you seeing? What are you expecting to see? What happens when your code runs to populate the cache?  Maybe include some screenshots of our cache to highlight where/how you think it's not working.  We use the platform cache in our managed package, and it works fine.

Comment: @NickCook I edited to add a link to screen shot of what the cache partition installed from the package looks like. Notice that "Provider Free" is "0" but it was packaged with "1". The goal is to just have it setup and ready to go when the package is installed. Also, I couldn't even allocate "Provider Free" once installed.

Comment: I have encountered this exact problem. I provided more details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=9062I000000UhW1QAK.

Comment: @user2943799 your link points to a question on Salesforce dev forums. The only response is a reference back to this question.

Comment: @James, yes i know -- I should have been more clear. The question I refer to does not have a resolution, but I provided a more detailed explanation of the problem there, which might be useful.